# Unable to click button functionality using selenium .click() method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Used script

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Create Tasks' and @type='button']")).click();
```

HTML code is as below -

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="formbuttonpane" align="center">
      <input type="button" tabindex="71" onclick="createTasks();" value="Create Tasks" style="width: 81pt;"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Question - I am unable to click on button, it is not working for above script. Please help me to understand what is the problem.

Comment: tbody>
<tr>
<td class="formbuttonpane" align="center">
<input type="button" tabindex="71" onclick="createTasks();" value="Create Tasks" style="width: 81pt;"/>
</td>
</tr>`
</tbody>

Comment: Review your question

Comment: What exception you get?

Comment: i am not getting any exception. Req is when i click the Create Task button it should save the date provided and leave the page. I am travelling through login page - Entertimetask page- Cteate Task page using windowhandels, when i do manually it works find but through script not.

Comment: After successfully execution, it display one popup - This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. but in manual process it wont ask .

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You can try this : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value=\"Create Tasks\" and @type=\"button\"]")).click();`

Comment: I'm sure OP can try it, but what is the point? There can be more than one input element on page

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value=\"Create Tasks\" and @type=\"button\"]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@value,'Create Tasks')]")).click();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Comment: Sandeep, with above xpath i can able to find element through firebug but on script it getting executed but button functionality is not working. it clicking the button but functionality is it should same the data move back to prev page, in my case its not going back to prev page.